# how can I hide some folder according to role based policy in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

There is a directory which is named Stackoverflow and there are sub directories such as stack, oveflow, webpages.

I want to see all folders when I log in using admin account.
I dont want to see all folders, I only want to see webpages directory when I log in using webdeveloper account.

I check the authentication from database. There is a table includes {AccountID, AuthenticationID, DirectoryName}.

```
AccountID {1: admin, 2: webdeveloper}
AuthenticationID { 1:show, 2:hide}

DirectoryName

--------------------------------------------------------
- AccountID      AuthenticationID       DirectoryName  -
--------------------------------------------------------
-  1           -         1           -   Stackoverflow -
--------------------------------------------------------
-  2           -         2          -    stack         -
--------------------------------------------------------
-  2           -         2          -    oveflow       -
--------------------------------------------------------
-  2           -         1          -    webpages      -
--------------------------------------------------------
```

on the other hand for webpages directory there are two more sub-directory, for instance pages, css.
and webdeveloper account should see only pages directory, not css.

any idea?
I control the directories and it workd but 
how can I control sub-directories such as css..

Thanx

Comment: You can add a web.config file in any directory and set the authorization to that folder.

Comment: I want to do it more programmaticaly, after login to system, admin can see and change all settings..

Comment: What's the problem with web.config solution?

Comment: how can admin change the web.config in a web application?

Comment: You can use xml manipulation to change the web.config

Comment: This is the same one. Put all authorization rules in the application root web.config and use xml manipulation in code to edit the file in run time. BTW, any saving action on web.config is restarting the application.